# Writing a regex pattern for text if not 255/255

Tags: regex, perl, text, scripting

I'm currently writing a Perl program where I need a regex pattern, but there is something I don't know how to do.

#### Text

```
Reliability: 255/255
```

I need to write a regex where if reliability is `255/255` then it's okay (I have that one: `Reliability:\s+(255\/255)`)
but if Reliability is different from `255/255` it's not.

I need to do it without an `else`. I just need the regex if possible.

**Clarification**

I send a command on a router : `show interface $WAN_Int` where `$WAN_Int` is an IP address. I put the result in a table. Then I read the table and I search for `Reliability: 255/255`. if it's ***255***, it's OK. If it's not, there is a problem.

Comment: Why using a regex? A simple comparison is  enough.

Comment: Okay, regardless of regex being totally unnecessary, and regardless of the redundant character classes, what exactly does your regex _not_ do while it should?

Comment: Having `[2][5][5]` in your regex is overkill - it's no different to have just "255" in it.

Comment: I'll check for comparison :) . To understand what I do : I send a command on a router : "show interface $WAN_Int" and I put the result in a table. Then I read the table and I search for "Reliability: 255/255". if it's 255 then it's OK. If it's not 255 there is a problem. I change [2][5][5] just after my question, it was a mistake :(

Comment: @AChichi Thanks for the clarification -- it should be a part of the question.  While one wants to be really careful with modifying a question after people have started looking at it, when a clarification is needed it is better to edit the question than to have it buried in a skinny comment :)

Comment: Okay thanks @zdim for the advice, I'm a beginner on stackoverflow :( Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
Reliability:\s+(?!255)\d+/255\s*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/1JAsG6/5/

Also, for matching 255 on your original regexp, It can be simplified (you don't need classes and you can avoid the group)

```
Reliability:\s+255/255\s*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/LnfXVI/3/

**NOTE**: If you use `/` as a delimiter for the regexp, you may need to scape `/` on the regxes as `\/`

**Extra**: If you would want to also disallow strings like `Reliability: 123456/255`, use this instead: `Reliability:\s+(?!255|0\d)\d{1,3}/255\s*$`

https://regex101.com/r/1JAsG6/8/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works well :)
I change [2][5][5] just after my question, it was a mistake.

Comment: Here is the context : I send a command on a router : "show interface $WAN_Int" and I put the result in a table. Then I read the table and I search for "Reliability: 255/255". if it's 255 then it's OK. If it's not 255 and there is a problem. So my condition is like this : if($_ =~ /Reliability:\s+((?!255\/255)\d+\/255)/) { #It's OK } I don't know if it's the best way to do it...

Comment: If the table can just contain strings like "Reliability: ..." then an approach like @zdim said, will work for you and It is a tad simpler. However, If on the table you can find some different strings (non "Reliability" ones) then you should use my approach in order to find Reliability strings with numbers != 255. Another option could be to search for Reliability strings and capture first number, and then check the value of the number. There are many options.

Comment: Okay, I'll use your option. I don't have only "Reliability" in my result. Thanks

Comment: The middle `255` is useless.

Comment: `Reliability:\s+255/255` matches `Reliability: 255/2550`

Comment: I finally used regex : Reliability:\s+((?!255\/255)\d+\/255$) and it's working well. Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 1):

```
my $ok = $string eq 'Reliability: 255/255';
```

or, if it must be a regex

```
my $ok = $string =~ m{^Reliability: 255/255$};
```

The `$ok` is `1` if `$string` is equal to the text or an empty string otherwise.

Both [`eq` operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) 
and the regex's [match operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) in scalar context
return "true" (`1`) on success or false (an empty string) otherwise. So you can use them in an expression and assign their return (or decide based on it).

Please keep in mind the precedence table when doing this or use parenthesis liberally.

Given the clarification a regex is better here, to allow for flexibility in input as it comes from another interface which may have (or pick up) slight variations in the expected format.

Then allow for multiple spaces between words (`\s+`), for the phrase being only a part of the string (drop anchors `^` and `$`), perhaps for the word not being capitalized

```
my $ok = $string =~ m{\b[Rr]eliability:\s+255/255\b};
```

where `\b` is the word-boundary anchor, since trailing numbers after `255` may compromise this.

Comment: Here is the context : I send a command on a router : "show interface $WAN_Int" and I put the result in a table. Then I read the table and I search for "Reliability: 255/255". if it's 255 then it's OK. If it's not 255 and there is a problem. So my condition is like this : if($_ =~ /Reliability:\s+((?!255\/255)\d+\/255)/) { #It's OK } I don't know if it's the best way to do it...

Comment: @AChichi OK, then a regex is better, since that input may have slight variations. I edited the answer.

Comment: I finally used regex : Reliability:\s+((?!255\/255)\d+\/255$) and it's working well. Thanks for your help :D